# How do I restrict the route?

Tags: ember.js

I have to restrict the user from re-routing page by changing the url in a browser. Is there any way to restrict it using ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. If you don't want the browser's URL to interact with your application at all, you can disable the location API

```
App.Router.reopen({
  location: 'none'
});
```

See http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/